# unable upload 3GB file using web interface

Tags: ubuntu-one, transfer

Today I tried (at least) two time upload about 3GB file - everythime progress dialog disappear and in status I got information '93% upload is done' - no error happen. No file available in UbuntuOne.

- System: Windows XP
- Browser: Chrome
- File type: .tar
- File size: about
  3GB

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever have this working - e.g. with small files?  A 3GB file isn't *that* big these days (unless you use really old operating systems or file systems that don't support files larger than 2GB), but it's always wise (and saves a lot of time) if you test things with small datasets/files first.  Also, right after attempting the copy, open a console and type dmesg.  A lot will scroll by, but the end of the file will show you system messages about anything that might have upset the operating system (Linux) when you ran the copy.